# OS X Outlook calculate message composition time

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I'm  using Outlook 2011 on Mac OS X, I'm trying to find a way to calculate the time it took to compose a message.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a Mac application, and should be migrated to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: What are your requirements on this? Does the program need to automatically know when a new message is being created, or can you manually start a script when you begin? How accurate does the time need to be? Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds? How do you want to be notified? Does it need logged, or would a dialog box be sufficient?

Comment: I'm trying to create time tracking application. This is to help the user automatically track their time that it took to respond to an email. I would like to get the "message to", "subject" and time it took to compose the message. The precision could be up to 5 minutes, but 1 minute is preferred.

Comment: (Sorry this is my first question here, I just hit enter to quickly).  Notification can be simple txt log.   From the research I did so far looks like AppleScript is the only option and it would have to be manually triggered to capture the start time? Am I correct? I'm open to any suggestions  thanks again !

Comment: What have you tried ? or are you expecting someone to do the work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to know the amount of minutes (not seconds), you can use [Atea](https://github.com/downloads/pkamenarsky/atea/atea-1.0.3.dmg). It's a super-simple time tracker that sits in your menu bar.

If you need the time down to the second, this is a somewhat ugly, but effective Applescript single use time tracker:

```
property logfile : "Path:To:log.txt"

set startTime to current date

--Don't let the dialog timeout. Give it an entire day to finish
with timeout of 86400 seconds
    display dialog "Click 'Finished' when your email is complete." buttons {"Finished"} default button "Finished"
end timeout

set elapsedTime to (current date) - startTime

--Opening and immediately closing the file just makes sure
--the file will exist when you try to write to it.
open for access file logfile with write permission
close access file logfile
write ((elapsedTime as string) & return) to file logfile starting at eof
```